# Is it possible to access digg's API from Flash without using a proxy to get around the cross-domain issues?

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml, digg

Is it possible to access digg's API from Flash without using a proxy to get around the cross-domain issues?

I'm a little confused because from googling it appears that the API has (atleast in the past) had a crossdomain.xml file but now trying to access services.digg.com/crossdomain.xml (from a browser, or looking at the response codes from the embedded flash calls to the API in Firebug/Chrome dev tools) results in a 403 error code, with the API error 1052(no method).

I am new to this, and working with someone else to get this implemented, so if there is something very simple to check config-wise, or else the answer is just-use-a-proxy, that's fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless the site you're trying to contact has a crossdomain.xml file on their server giving you access, then you won't be able to do this.

I have this exact problem with the StumbleUpon API, where they actually *have* a crossdomain.xml file, but they don't allow external access: http://getsatisfaction.com/stumbleupon/topics/update_of_the_cross_domain_policy_files_for_swf_files

You'll need to use a proxy if you can't get them to change this.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that, I just read a lot of things to the effect that they had a crossdomain.xml file, and I couldn't find evidence of that, nor any news that they've taken it down(though I know there's a new API) which was a little confusing. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, i think it came over with the new api/redesign as i remember doing this before

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a proxy I guess, I'm not aware of alternatives solutions (except asking on their forum why it's not online anymore)